# Authentication of id and password in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 2 methods in my testcase.

method 1 :

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddUser()
{
    firefox = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
    firefox.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://<code><code>domain</code></code>:44220/learn-language-online/");
    firefox.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sign In")).Click();
    firefox.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.watermarkify-watermark-inner")).Click();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Username")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Username")).SendKeys("rachana@prakashinfotech.com");
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("123456");
    firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(text(),'Sign In')])[2]")).Click();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
    OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions builder = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(firefox);
    IWebElement elem = firefox.FindElement(By.ClassName("icon"));
    builder.MoveToElement(elem).Build().Perform();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
    firefox.FindElement(By.LinkText("Manage Users")).Click();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("FirstName")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("FirstName")).SendKeys("Kashyap");
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("LastName")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("LastName")).SendKeys("Khanna");
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("123");
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("ConfirmPassword")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("ConfirmPassword")).SendKeys("123");
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Email")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Email")).SendKeys("kashyap@gmail.com");
    new SelectElement(firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Languages"))).SelectByText("India");
    new SelectElement(firefox.FindElement(By.Id("DifficultyLevels"))).SelectByText("Level 1");
    new SelectElement(firefox.FindElement(By.Id("MaturityLevels"))).SelectByText("Everyone");
    firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[2]/span")).Click();      
 }
```

method 2 :

```
[TestMethod]
public void AssignCourse()
{
    firefox = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
    firefox.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://<code>domain</code>:44220/Home/Index");
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
    OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions builder = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(firefox);
    IWebElement elem = firefox.FindElement(By.ClassName("icon"));
    builder.MoveToElement(elem).Build().Perform();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
    firefox.FindElement(By.LinkText("Manage Users")).Click();
    firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='divUser_84700']/div[2]/div/div/a[2]")).Click();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
    firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("(//img[@alt='Delete'])[5]")).Click();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80));
    firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id='addCourses']/span")).Click();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80));
    firefox.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.class_73.courseItem > a > span.detail")).Click();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
    firefox.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.class_87.courseItem > a > span.detail")).Click();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("btnAddCourse")).Click();

}
```

now when my 1st method get tested and it moves to 2nd method session of uesrid and password not get maintained and because of that i am not able to navigate my url to http://`domain`:44220/Home/Index. so how to solve the issue of authentication.

Comment: Dont create a new instance of firefox in your second method, use the same instance of firefox which you have used in method 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `firefox = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();`
 in a setup method may be in @BeforeTest, it makesures that there is only one instance of firefoxdriver  is running for the entire set of tests.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options.

1. You can use cookie:

   ```
   Cookie ck = new Cookie("name", "value");
   driver.manage().addCookie(ck);
   ```

(code in java)
Operation on cookie - http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Cookie.html

2. You can use [Page Object Pattern](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) it is best practice to create test code. You can then call method to log in from @Before or @BeforeTest annotation etc. I encourage you to reaad about Page Object Pattern because it helps writing maintanable, and cleaner test code

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver creates a new Firefox profile every time you launch the browser so any cookies or whatever session parameters are lost. Meaning, you have to log in again. That would be:

```
private WebDriver firefox;

private void LogIn()
{
    firefox = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver();
    firefox.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://<code><code>domain</code></code>:44220/learn-language-online/");
    firefox.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sign In")).Click();
    firefox.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.watermarkify-watermark-inner")).Click();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Username")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Username")).SendKeys("rachana@prakashinfotech.com");
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("123456");
    firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(text(),'Sign In')])[2]")).Click();     
 }


[TestMethod]
public void AddUser()
{
    LogIn();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
    OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions builder = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(firefox);
    IWebElement elem = firefox.FindElement(By.ClassName("icon"));
    builder.MoveToElement(elem).Build().Perform();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
    firefox.FindElement(By.LinkText("Manage Users")).Click();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("FirstName")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("FirstName")).SendKeys("Kashyap");
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("LastName")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("LastName")).SendKeys("Khanna");
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("123");
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("ConfirmPassword")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("ConfirmPassword")).SendKeys("123");
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Email")).Clear();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Email")).SendKeys("kashyap@gmail.com");
    new SelectElement(firefox.FindElement(By.Id("Languages"))).SelectByText("India");
    new SelectElement(firefox.FindElement(By.Id("DifficultyLevels"))).SelectByText("Level 1");
    new SelectElement(firefox.FindElement(By.Id("MaturityLevels"))).SelectByText("Everyone");
    firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[2]/span")).Click();      
 }


[TestMethod]
public void AssignCourse()
{
    LogIn();
    firefox.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://<code>domain</code>:44220/Home/Index");
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
    OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions builder = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(firefox);
    IWebElement elem = firefox.FindElement(By.ClassName("icon"));
    builder.MoveToElement(elem).Build().Perform();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
    firefox.FindElement(By.LinkText("Manage Users")).Click();
    firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='divUser_84700']/div[2]/div/div/a[2]")).Click();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
    firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("(//img[@alt='Delete'])[5]")).Click();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80));
    firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id='addCourses']/span")).Click();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80));
    firefox.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.class_73.courseItem > a > span.detail")).Click();
    firefox.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
    firefox.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.class_87.courseItem > a > span.detail")).Click();
    firefox.FindElement(By.Id("btnAddCourse")).Click();

}
```

Comment: Here every time new method calls i have to do login process.Is there any way that i don't have to call login() method again and again and i can get the userid and password once 1st method of login is done and i can use it in every other methods.